# Ruby: how to split a collection by predicate into two collections in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to separate the elements of a single collection by some predicate
into two collections, one containing the YES-elements, the other containing to NO-elements.
I want to do that in only one iteration and I want to avoid temporary copies.
The following works for me:

```
irb> aaa = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]; bbb = [];
irb> aaa.reject!{|n| bbb<<n unless n.odd? }
irb> bbb
 # => [2, 4, 6, 8]
irb> aaa
 # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

but I wonder, is there a better more readable solution  *AND*
is there something like this for a Hash?

*Update:* see this [Ruby: how to split a collection (Enumerable) in multiple (>2) partitions by some predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334162)

Comment: I quite like your solution frankly.

Comment: "AND is there something like this for a Hash?" - that's a very vague question. How do you actually want to split it? By keys or values? Whats the desired output. This is probally better suited as a separate question.

Comment: my focus was on the splitting not on the predicate - so any kind of predicate.
but the splitting should output two collections of the same "type" as the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

> `partition { |obj| block } → [ true_array, false_array ]`
> `partition → an_enumerator`
>
> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for
> which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

```
irb(main):011:0> (1..10).partition(&:odd?)
=> [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks! To be complete, the same for Hashes:   

    odds,evens = { 1 => :one, 2 => :two }.partition{|k,v| k.odd? }.map( &:to_h )